# Passing by value?

Tags: c#, function, copy, pass-by-value

I am having an issue with C# function argument passing.

I was wondering how would I make a C# function accept a parameter by value (to make a copy of the original object).

I thought that was the default way C# handled these things, but in the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class MaximumElement
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack<int> numbers = new Stack<int>();
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (input)
            {
                case "2": numbers.Pop(); break;
                case "3": Console.WriteLine(maxElement(numbers)); break;
                default:
                    string[] argz = input.Split(' ');
                    numbers.Push(int.Parse(argz[1]));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public static int maxElement(Stack<int> stack)
    {
        int max = stack.Peek();
        for (int i = 0; i < stack.Count; i++)
        {
            if (max >= stack.Peek())
            {
                stack.Pop();
            }
            else if (max < stack.Peek())
            {
                max = stack.Pop();
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

My **`maxElement()`** function actually changes the original stack I pass to it, and the only way to get around it is to manually make a copy of the stack I pass to the function inside the function. 
Thanks for any responses in advance :)

Comment: C# *is* passing the argument by value, but the argument is a reference. If you want to make a copy, you'll need to do so explicitly. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html for details on C# parameter passing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the useful answer . Is there any way I can pass my stack as a  value parameter? (I'm guessing I should make a stack that is equal to a "new" stack<>) ?

Comment: It's already a value parameter, and the value is a reference. You need to distinguish between parameter passing and reference/value types and cloning. `new Stack<int>(stack)` is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little complex.  From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx):

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it persist outside the block. To do that, pass the parameter using the ref or out keyword. For simplicity, the following examples use ref.

Here is the code example they provide:

```
static void Change(int[] pArray)
{
    pArray[0] = 888;  // This change affects the original element.
    pArray = new int[5] {-3, -1, -2, -3, -4};   // This change is local.
```

Now, if you use the `ref` keyword on your parameter

```
static void Change(ref int[] pArray)
{
    pArray[0] = 888;  // This change affects the original element.
    pArray = new int[5] {-3, -1, -2, -3, -4};   // This change also affects the original
```

So, with those things in mind, you could...

```
public static int maxElement(Stack<int> stack)
{
    stack = new Stack<int>(stack); // Now changes will be local

    int max = stack.Peek();
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.Count; i++)
    {
        if (max >= stack.Peek())
        {
            stack.Pop();
        }
        else if (max < stack.Peek())
        {
            max = stack.Pop();
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix passing arguments by *value* or *reference* with *value types* and *reference types*. Its a common beginner's mistake and you need to have a clear understanding of how both things, allthough related in some way, are completely different features of the language.

I'll probably not use precise terminology because english is not my language but I hope I can get the idea across:

- Value type: The variable is the value itself. When you write the following: `int i = 1;` the variable `i` holds the value `1`.
- Reference type: The variable is a reference that points to a place in memory where the object is. That means that, when you say `string s = "Hello";` `s` does not contain `"Hello"`, it contains the memory address where `"Hello"` is stored.

So what happens when you pass an argument by value (default in C#). We have two possibilities:

- Argument is a value type: You get a copy of the variable, that means
  that if you pass along `i = 1` you recieve a *copy* which also
  contains `1`, but *both* are alltogether different objects.

  This is obvious when dealing with *mutable* value types, for example `System.Drawing.Point`:

  ```
  Point point = new Point(0, 0);

  Frob(point);
  var b = point.X == 1 && point.Y == 1; //False, point does not change.

  void Frob(Point p) { p.Offset(1, 1); } // p is a copy of point and therefore contains a copy of the value stored in point, not the value itself.
  ```
- Argument is a reference type: You get a copy of the variable, that means you get a *copy of the reference to the memory address*, but the object the copy is pointing at *is the same*. This is the scenario you are in.

  ```
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.Blah = 1;

  Frob(foo);
  var b = foo.Blah == 2; //True, foo.Blah has been modified.

  void Frob(Foo f) { foo.Blah = 2; } //both foo and f point to the same object.
  ```

  Notice that in both cases what you can't do is modify *what* the reference is pointing to. This won't work:

  ```
  string s = "hello";
  foo(s);
  var b = s == "bye"; //false, s still points to the original string

  void Foo(string str)
  {
      str = "bye";
  }
  ```

Now, what happens if we pass by reference? Well, the main difference is that you are passing the variable itself, not a copy. That means that in case of a value type you are passing the original value and in case of a reference type, the original address, not a copy. This allows the following:

```
    //Value type
    Point point = new Point(0, 0);

    Frob(ref point);
    var b = point.X == 1 && point.Y == 1; //True, point and p are the same variable.

    void Frob(ref Point p) { p.Offset(1, 1); }
```

and

```
    //Value or reference type
    string s = "hello";
    foo(ref s);
    var b = s == "bye"; //true

    void Foo(ref string str)
    {
        str = "bye";
    }
```

Hope this clarifies the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make a copy of the Stack, which if a shallow copy works you can use [Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.clone(v=vs.110).aspx)() method.